# Flycheck r-lintr doesn't find anything

Tags: flycheck, ess, ubuntu

I want to use `lintr` to check R-files in emacs.
According to https://github.com/jimhester/lintr#emacs

> lintr is fully integrated into flycheck when using ESS. See the installalation documentation for those packages for more information.

So per http://ess.r-project.org/index.php?Section=download I installed ess(version 17.11-2) via `sudo apt-get install ess` (I'm on ubuntu), and for flycheck I installed `flycheck` via MELPA.

Upon restart ESS is loaded automatically when opening an `*.R` file, for `flycheck` I type `M-x flycheck` (for simplicity, I didn't put the usepackage line in init.el)

On `M-x flycheck-buffer` nothing happened and `M-x flycheck-verify-checker` said that the library wasn't present, so I installed lintr as `install.packages("lintr")` in an R shell.

Now `M-x flycheck-verify-checker` `r-lintr` is all green:

```
 r-lintr
   - major mode:    `ess-mode' supported
   - may enable:    yes
   - predicate:     t
   - executable:    Found at /usr/bin/R
   - lintr library: present

Flycheck can use this syntax checker for this buffer.
```

With `M-x flycheck-buffer` you can see that it is working (there"s an `*` next to `FlyC` in the status bar) but ulimately nothing is found, while in an R shell `lintr::lint("myfile.R")` finds a lot!

Versions:
GNU Emacs 25.2.2
Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

### Progress:

#### Philopolis' answer:

1)
flycheck is now loaded automatically, but still errors are not found

2) the ess in Melpa is `Incompatible` because it depends on `julia-mode-0.3 (not available)` I'll look into that, [Unable to install ESS package](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/48341) seems promising.
I've added Melpa stable and installed ess, but to no avail: While in other languages flycheck complains about trivial stuff like to many/view  spaces, in `R` superfluous parenthesis go unnoticed.

Comment: julia-mode, which is an ESS dependency, removed their stable tags a while back so you'll have to install it from MELPA, not MELPA-stable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `C-c ! C-c` for `r-lintr` and check the output. In my case, I discovered that flycheck was not finding the `/home/user/.R/lintr_cache` directory -- the problem went away once I created it.

Comment: `mkdir -p  ~/.R/lintr_cache` did the trick! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I also had trouble making Flycheck work with ESS. I don't know if this will work for you but here are some tips that solved the problems for me:

**1)** Disable Flymake (at least for ESS), since it seems that Flycheck and Flymake can trigger some odd conflicts. Add the following lines in your init file:

```
(require 'ess-site) ;; load ESS
(setq ess-use-flymake nil) ;; disable Flymake
```

While you are in your init file, you could also add the following lines to enable Flycheck globally :

```
(require 'flycheck)
(global-flycheck-mode t)
```

**2)** If Flycheck still does not work, try to install the latest version of ESS from MELPA. Installing ESS from my distro repo (I was on openSuse Leap) resulted in a lot of problems I didn't have anymore when I switched to the ESS versions from Melpa (or even Melpa-stable, which was just as old).